# Laravel API Resources missing meta values for pagination

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm trying to return paginated collection for my API but current_page, `last_page`, `per_page`, `total` etc keys are missing from `meta`. Not sure what's wrong with the code.

BillingCollection.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources\Billing;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class BillingCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection,
        ];
    }
}
```

BillingResource.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources\Billing;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class BillingResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'uuid' => $this->uuid,
        ];
    }
}
```

Calling collection with paginate

```
return BillingResource::collection($billings->paginate());
//return new BillingCollection($billings->paginate()); -> Tried this as well
```

My response :
[image]
Response it should return :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to github source, you have this method `getData()`, you can chain your response like:

```
return BillingResource::collection($billings->paginate())->response()->getData(true);
```

Documentation here: https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html#method_getData

Give a try, it's a kind of ugly way in any case since you are chaining 2 responses but it should work.

Answer (score -1):

The paginate function in Laravel is designed to work with Eloquent query builder instances, specifically those representing database models. It is not a generic function that can be used with any array or collection of data.
To include pagination meta values in your Laravel API Resources collection

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => BillingResource::collection($this->collection),
        'meta' => [
            'pagination' => [
                'total' => $this->total(),
                'count' => $this->count(),
                'per_page' => $this->perPage(),
                'current_page' => $this->currentPage(),
                'total_pages' => $this->lastPage(),
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Now,when you

```
return BillingResource::collection($billings->paginate());
```

it will include the pagination meta values in the response.